# Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I've got ES cluster on Azure, and communicate with it from Spring Boot app using elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient.

The bean in spring is the follow

```
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchRestClient() {
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(ipAddress, port))
            .setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder.setConnectTimeout(10000).setSocketTimeout(90000))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpAsyncClientBuilder ->
                    httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
    Sniffer sniffer = Sniffer.builder(restHighLevelClient.getLowLevelClient()).setSniffIntervalMillis(60000).build();
    return restHighLevelClient;
}
```

Here ipAddress is loadbalancer's ip on Azure ES cluster, port is 9200. 
The problem is - if ES idle for few minutes - next request to ES fails with SocketTimeoutException.

> 2019-09-26T07:20:50.228101050Z: [INFO] 
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 90,000 milliseconds timeout on
>   connection http-outgoing-5 [ACTIVE] 2019-09-26T07:20:50.228104650Z:
>   [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:773)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]
>   2019-09-26T07:20:50.228108350Z: [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:218)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]
>   2019-09-26T07:20:50.228111750Z: [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]
>   2019-09-26T07:20:50.228115350Z: [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]
>   2019-09-26T07:20:50.228118850Z: [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1439)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]
>   2019-09-26T07:20:50.228122150Z: [INFO]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:784)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.3.2.jar!/:7.3.2]

After this fail, retry attemp finishes succesfully.

I've tried to add sniffer on LowLevelRestClient - but no effect.

What can be the possible trouble?
Thanks!

Comment: Is  Azure => Always On activated ?

Comment: @LeBigCat do you mean all Azure infrastracture? Or some specific ES part? If whole infrastracture - yes, the app which calls ES client is in Azure App Service and it is polling Azure's queue for messages. Also, if I'm sending requests to ES's loadbalancer using cURL - it works well

Comment: Well, should be on loadbalancer side then. You got the same error with a curl rest ? or head plugin(i mean without using java client)?

Comment: @LeBigCat with curl it works well, no errors

Comment: Can you remake a try with setConnectionRequestTimeout(0) ?

Comment: @LeBigCat thanks, i saw this advice, but unfortunately it doesn't help in my case. Also I tried to icrease idle timeout in azure's external loadbalancer ip config, but again - same error